# Let $f:[0,1]\to\Bbb{R}$ a continuous function which is differentiable in $(0,1)$, but is not in $0$ and $1$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

I need to draw a graphic which the function is differentiable in whole $(0,1)$ but is not in $0$ and $1$.
I just can imagine the function $f(x)=cotg(\frac{x}{\pi})$ but this $f$ is not well-defined in $[0,1]$, despiste being not differentiable at $0$ and $1$.

Comment: How about $f(x) = \sqrt{1/4-(1/2-x)^2}$? It's the upper part of a circle centered at $(1/2, 0)$.

Comment: Well... the question about differentiability is confuse. If the function is differentiable in $(0,1)$ and continuous in $[0,1]$ then **is** differentiable in $0$ and $1$. It doesnt make sense to ask for the lateral limit of a function where is not defined.

Comment: @JackyChong I've seen it written otherwise: $\sqrt{1-x}\sqrt{x}$ and it, indeed, could work. Thankyou!!

Comment: Oh, I assumed it meant not differentiable *at* 0 and 1.  "In" 0 and "in" 1 doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Any thing that's differentiable on (0,1) and then veers with a sharp angle at 0,1 will do it.  |x (x_1)| is a classic.

Comment: Yeah! My english... sorry. You assumed right. Is "at" a point.

Comment: How exactly are you defining differentiability at a boundary point? Is nondifferentiability at 0 (or 1) just referring to the left (or right) derivative failing to exist? In that case you'll want to make it blow up, as Jacky's example does.

Comment: I should have said: nondifferentiability at 0 refers to the right derivative failing to exist and nondifferentiability at 1 refers to the left derivative failing to exist.

Comment: @Masacroso ... yeah, I thought so too.  BUT if lim f'(x) = \pm infinity whereas lim f(x) = f(x) finite will be a case where it is not differentiable.  Example $f(x) = \sqrt[3]{x}$ is continuous and differentiable everywhere but x = 0.

Answer (score 2):

Oh, I missed the restriction that the domain of $f$ is $[0,1]$.  If $f$ is differentiable on $(0,1)$ and continuous on $[0,1]$ and nonexistent on $(-\infty,0)$ and $(1, \infty)$ this is impossible unless $\lim f'(x) = \pm \infty$.

$f'(0) = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0^+}\frac{f(h) - f(0)}{h}$.

As $f$ is continuous $f(0) = lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+} f(x)$ so

$f'(0) = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0^+}\frac{f(h) - f(0)}{h}= \lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}\lim_{h\rightarrow x^+}\frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+} f'(x)$

So is differentiable at $x = 0$ if the limit exists.  Likewise:

$f'(1) = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0^+}\frac{f(1-h) - f(1)}{-h}$.

As $f$ is continuous $f(1) = lim_{x\rightarrow 1^-} f(x)$ so

$f'(1) = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0^+}\frac{f(h) - f(0)}{h}= \lim_{x\rightarrow 1^-}\lim_{h\rightarrow x^-}\frac{f(x-h) - f(x)}{-h}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 1^-} f'(x)$

So is differentiable at $x=1$ if the limit exist.

So we want a function where $lim f(x)$ exists but $\lim f'(x)$ doesn't.

Graphically a function that goes vertical at $x= 0,1$ will do this. ie.

$f(x) = \sqrt{\frac 14 - (\frac 12 - x)^2}$

[$f'(x) = -\frac 2{\sqrt{\frac 14 - (\frac 12 - x)^2}2 (\frac 12 - x)^2}$ which is defined for $0 < x < 1$ but undefined at $x=0$ or $x=1$]

**BUT** if $f:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ where $f$ is continuous and $f$ is differentiable on $(0,1)$ but not differentiable at $0$ or $1$ is certainly possible if $f$ "goes off at a sharp angle" at 0 and 1.

Examples: $f(x) = |x(x-1)|$.  for $f(x) = 0; x < 0; f(x) = x; 0 \le x \le 1; f(x) = 1; x > 1$ or $f(x) = x^2; x < 0; f(x)=x; 0 \le x \le 1; f(x)=-x^3 + 2; x > 1$, etc.

In all of these $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0^+}\frac{f(x + h) - f(x)}{h}\ne \lim_{h\rightarrow 0^-}\frac{f(x + h) - f(x)}{h}$ at $x = 0$ or $x=1$ so are not differentiable there.

Answer (score 2):

You've already seen
$$
f_{1}(x) = \sqrt{x - x^{2}},
$$
whose graph is the top half of a circle over $[0, 1]$; other examples include suitable scalings of $\arccos$ or $\arcsin$, such as
$$
f_{2}(x) = \arcsin\bigr(\tfrac{1}{2}(1 + x)\bigr),
$$
which again has vertical tangents at the endpoints.

To get more spectacular failure, try something like
$$
f_{3}(x) = f_{1}(x) \sin\left(\frac{1}{f_{1}(x)^{n}}\right),\quad n \geq 1,
$$
extended by continuity to be $0$ at the endpoints. Here, the derivative oscillates (and is unbounded) near each endpoint, so the endpoint derivatives do not exist even if you allow $\pm\infty$ as values.

[image: A continuous function on a closed interval, differentiable only on the open interval]

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: First, find a continuous function $g$ on $[0,1]$ differentiable everywhere except $0$. Let $h(x)=g(x)\cdot(x-\frac{1}{2})^2$ -- it will have the same properties, but the derivative at $\frac{1}{2}$ will be $0$. Then put $$f(x)=\begin{cases} h(x) \textrm{ if }x<\frac{1}{2}\\ h(1-x)\textrm{ if }x\geq \frac{1}{2}.\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x) = x \sin \frac {1}{x} + (1-x) \sin \frac {1}{1-x} \;\;\;\;\text{with}\;\; f(0) = f(1) = \sin 1$$

It is straightforward to show that the function is continuous on $[0,1]$, differentiable on $(0,1)$, but is not differentiable at $\{0,1\}$. Its graph can be plotted at [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x+sin(1%2Fx)+%2B+(1-+x)+sin(1%2F(1-x))+for+0+%3C+x+%3C+1).

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply $f (x)=x$ if $0 \le x \le 1$.$  f (x)=0 $ if $x <0$ and $f (x)=1$ if $x>1$?

$f $ is continuous and not differentiable at $0$ or $1$.

Comment: Flea, "f (x)=x if 0=<1"?? I don't get it. And I think this f is not well-defined in [0,1].

Comment: @LucasBarbiere, it's well defined and continuous in $[0,1]$.  Try graphing it.

Comment: Tilper, and about f (x)=x if 0 =<1? What does it means? Would be "0=<x=<1"? And why is not differentiable at 0 and 1... I can't see it.

Comment: If the domain of the function is $[0,1]$ then this is just the function $f(x)=x$. This kind of subtlety is part of why derivatives are usually defined on open sets.

Comment: That was a type.  f(x) = x if 0 < x < 1.

Comment: It's not differentiable at 0 and 1 because the limits from the left are different than the limits from the right.  $f'(x) = 0; x < 0$  f'(x) = 1; 0<x<1$ f'(x) = 0; x > 1$.  At x=0 or x = 1 then $ f'(x) = lim (f(x+h)-f(x))/h$ will have different values whether h is negative or positive.

Comment: "If the domain of the function is [0,1]"... oh,  if the domain is [0,1] is is not possible to take the limit from above or below so there will be only one limit and a non-differential set is impossible.